# Django MongoDB Fields (empty and null)

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

I've written a model that has a field that can be blank, not null, and is not required. When I create and save an instance of the model without including data corresponding to such field, django still saves such field with an empty string value. My question is, is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Set `default=None` in your field definition: `foo = models.CharField(..., default=None)`.

Comment: I did following this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes -, but it didn't work. I got the following error: AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class Question

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. It still saves all the fields.

Comment: any solutions to this?